# Error: Unresolved Reference after minor code changes

Tags: android, kotlin, jetpack

I am experiencing a weird error. My App has several screens that are managed by a NavGraph. Each screen has its own ViewModel and these are managed by a ViewModelProvider. Everything works fine.

While adding a new screen, I always got the same error, that every entry about a specific other screen resulted in an unresolved reference. As I said, without the new screen it works fine, but I played around and by adding an empty line somewhere in either the NavGraph or the ViewModelProvider I get the errors that this one screen is unresolved.

Whats causing these problems? I really dont get it.

Thanks

- Updated Android Studio
- Restart of IDE